# Enviar foco al primer campo vacío del formulario Java

Tags: java, focus

Tengo un formulario con diferentes campos `jTextField` para agregar a nuevos clientes.

**¿Cómo se podría hacer para que obtenga el foco el primer campo que haya vacío en mi formulario?**

El orden que quiero otorgar sería: nombre - apellidos - dni - telefono - direccion - ciudad - email.

**Código:**

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Atributos generales para el cliente.
        String nombre = textfield_nombre.getText();
        String apellidos = textfield_apellidos.getText();
        String DNI = textfield_DNI.getText();
        String telefono = textfield_telefono.getText();
        String direccion = textfield_direccion.getText();
        String ciudad = textfield_ciudad.getText();
        String email = textfield_email.getText();

        //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
        if (!textfield_nombre.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_apellidos.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                && !textfield_DNI.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_telefono.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                && !textfield_direccion.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_ciudad.getText().trim().isEmpty()
                && !textfield_email.getText().trim().isEmpty()
            ) {
            if(!isDNI(textfield_DNI.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Formato de DNI incorrecto!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_DNI.requestFocus();
            }else if(!isEmail(textfield_email.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Formato de email incorrecto!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_email.requestFocus();
            }else if(Conexiones.cargar_email().contains(textfield_email.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este email YA existe en la agenda!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_email.requestFocus();
            }else if(!Conexiones.cargar_dni().contains(textfield_DNI.getText())) {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
                //Llamamos al método alta_cliente() para insertar el cliente en la base de datos.
                Conexiones.alta_cliente(cliente);
                dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este DNI ya EXISTE en la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_DNI.requestFocus();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!!!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_nombre.requestFocus();
            textfield_nombre.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veís, he dado click a `OK`, y ha comprobado que existe un campo vacío, entonces manda el foco al campo `NOMBRE` debido a que puse "`textfield_nombre.requestFocus();`", ¿pero **cómo puedo hacer llevar el foco al PRIMER campo vacío existent**e en el orden que anteriormente dije?

Existiría esta posibilidad pero no lleva el foco como yo quiero:

```
private boolean validateForm() {
    for(int i=0; i<Panel_Cliente.getComponentCount(); i++) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent)Panel_Cliente.getComponent(i);
        if(c instanceof JTextField) {
            if(((JTextField)c).getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                ((JTextField)c).requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a cuando entra en el `else` porque al menos uno está vacío? Pues en vez de hacer el `requestFocus` para el `nombre`, tendrás que comprobar uno a uno en tu orden cual es el que está vacío y hacer el `requestFocus` a ese. El primero que esté vacío toma el foco y terminas.

Comment: @SuperG280 Si, opción factible pero poco usual, ¿y si en vez de tener 7 campos tengo 200? ¿No habría una opción para hacerlo más general?

Comment: La verdad es que no se me ocurre... ¿Vas a hacer un formulario con 200 campos? Pobre del usuario que tenga que rellenarlos todos :) Es broma. Realmente no se me ocurre si no es recorriéndolos todos uno a uno.

Comment: Ese programa está usando el `GroupLayout`.... si o no?

Comment: mmm está creado en java Swing, elementos alineados pero no sé que layout está usando.